# Spring MVC Simple Redirect Controller Example

Tags: jsf, spring-mvc

Hi I'm trying to compare the redirect methods of various frameworks.

I've made it through quite a few:

- [Cakephp](http://cakephp.org/)
- [CodeIgniter](http://codeigniter.com/)
- [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)
- [Grails](http://grails.org/)
- [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/)
- [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/)

However I'm stuck trying to create the simplest example possible for [Spring MVC](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#mvc) and [JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5346015/jsf-simple-redirect-controller-example).

What I want is either one or two controllers which handle the /index and /redirect urls where /index simply links to /redirect, and /redirect uses a 301 redirect to redirect back to /index.

I found [this documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting), I just don't have the persistence to figure out how to create this seemingly simple example in Spring MVC.

Thanks!

Comment: As of spring 3.0, the old framework for SimpleFormController is deprecated.  If you are starting from scratch I suggest you use the [Spring 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/mvc.html) documentation instead.

Comment: You've linked to the Spring 2.0.x docs, which is a 5 year old version of Spring. Not a good place to start.

Comment: Also, you don't generally use Spring MVC *and* JSF. You use one or the other.

Comment: I wanted two independent examples. One for Spring MVC and one for JSF thus it seems appropriate that they were two independent questions especially since they span multiple frameworks.

Comment: out of interest did you ever blog about the redirect methods?

Comment: No, though we wrote a paper with a framework analysis section (2.4). We ended up excluding JSF and Spring from our analysis: http://cs.ucsb.edu/~bboe/public/pubs/fear-the-ear-ccs2011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Just incase I played with redirect in JSF and SPring MVC:

JSF:

```
  <navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>index.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-action>#{actionController.actionSubmitted}</from-action>
        <from-outcome>success</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>index.xhtml</to-view-id>
        <redirect />
    </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
```

Spring-MVC submitting user form in POST/REdirect/GET design pattern:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/index.html", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
    User user = new User();
        mv.addObject("user", user);
    return mv;
}

 @RequestMapping(value="/signin.html",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelAndView submit(@Valid User user){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("redirect:index.html"); 
    System.out.println(user.getFirstName());
    return mv;
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a bit more concerned with how to actually get a server up and running with these controllers though. For instance with django/rails/groovy I run a command to create the framework skeleton code, then add my controller code, and finally run a single command to get a dev. server up and running. It seems not as simple for either of these frameworks.